# How to monitor ip address change using RTNETLINK socket in go language

Tags: go, ip-address, netlink

I have following code, which should monitor network changes using RTNETLINK socket. However when I am setting new IP address for interface "New Addr" or "Del Addr" does not showing. What can be possible problem.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    l, _ := ListenNetlink()

    for {
        msgs, err := l.ReadMsgs()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not read netlink: %s", err)
        }

        for _, m := range msgs {
            if IsNewAddr(&m) {
                fmt.Println("New Addr")
            }

            if IsDelAddr(&m) {
                fmt.Println("Del Addr")
            }
        }
    }
}

type NetlinkListener struct {
    fd int
    sa *syscall.SockaddrNetlink
}

func ListenNetlink() (*NetlinkListener, error) {
    groups := syscall.RTNLGRP_LINK |
        syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR |
        syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR

    s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_NETLINK, syscall.SOCK_DGRAM,
        syscall.NETLINK_ROUTE)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("socket: %s", err)
    }

    saddr := &syscall.SockaddrNetlink{
        Family: syscall.AF_NETLINK,
        Pid:    uint32(0),
        Groups: uint32(groups),
    }

    err = syscall.Bind(s, saddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("bind: %s", err)
    }

    return &NetlinkListener{fd: s, sa: saddr}, nil
}

func (l *NetlinkListener) ReadMsgs() ([]syscall.NetlinkMessage, error) {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()

    pkt := make([]byte, 2048)

    n, err := syscall.Read(l.fd, pkt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("read: %s", err)
    }

    msgs, err := syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage(pkt[:n])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse: %s", err)
    }

    return msgs, nil
}

func IsNewAddr(msg *syscall.NetlinkMessage) bool {
    if msg.Header.Type == syscall.RTM_NEWADDR {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func IsDelAddr(msg *syscall.NetlinkMessage) bool {
    if msg.Header.Type == syscall.RTM_DELADDR {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func IsRelevant(msg *syscall.IfAddrmsg) bool {
    if msg.Scope == syscall.RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE ||
        msg.Scope == syscall.RT_SCOPE_SITE {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I found bag in `syscall.go` file. Constant variable `syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR=0x5`. However analog `RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR` constant in C language which is defined in [`rtnetlink.h` source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/rtnetlink.h#L578) has different value as following:</s>

```
#define RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR 0x10
```

I submitted [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15080) through github.com and I hope it will fixed in upcoming releases.

For now you can use `0x10` in your code insted of `0x5`. It will work perfectly.

Turns out that it is not bug at all. They did not re declare `RTMGRP_*` constant variables group from [`rtnetlink.h` source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/rtnetlink.h#L578) and do not want to add this in feature as well since `syscall.go` is frozen. However they suggest using `RTNLGRP_*` which is also declared in [`rtnetlink.h` source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/rtnetlink.h#L578). However this two groups of constant variables is different in following way. `RTMGRP_*` group represents bit value (i.e.: `RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR = 0x10`) and declared for userspace backward capabilities. `RTLNGRP_*` group represents bit position rather than bit value (i.e.: `RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR=0x5`) which can be translated to bit value by following way `1 << (RTNLGRP_* - 1)`

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. Can you update the example code above accordingly?

Answer (score 3):

As per the accepted answer, the fix it to change the `groups` to the following:

```
groups := (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_LINK - 1)) |
    (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR - 1)) |
    (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR - 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the equivalent code for *BSD:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    netlink, err := ListenNetlink()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[ERR] Could not create netlink listener: %v", err)
        return
    }

    for {
        msgs, err := netlink.ReadMsgs()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("[ERR] Could not read netlink: %v", err)
        }

        for _, msg := range msgs {
            if _, ok := msg.(*syscall.InterfaceAddrMessage); ok {
                log.Printf("address change!")
            }
        }
    }
}

type NetlinkListener struct {
    fd int
}

func ListenNetlink() (*NetlinkListener, error) {
    s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_ROUTE, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.AF_UNSPEC)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("socket: %s", err)
    }
    return &NetlinkListener{fd: s}, nil
}

func (l *NetlinkListener) ReadMsgs() ([]syscall.RoutingMessage, error) {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()

    pkt := make([]byte, 2048)

    n, err := syscall.Read(l.fd, pkt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("read: %s", err)
    }

    msgs, err := syscall.ParseRoutingMessage(pkt[:n])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse: %s", err)
    }

    return msgs, nil
}
```

Comment: How the example would look like for Darwin/macOS?

Comment: @surlac above code works on Darwin/MacOS any other BSD'sh operating system

Answer (score 0):

the update Example should be

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    l, _ := ListenNetlink()

    for {
        msgs, err := l.ReadMsgs()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Could not read netlink: %s", err)
        }

        for _, m := range msgs {
            if IsNewAddr(&m) {
                fmt.Println("New Addr")
            }

            if IsDelAddr(&m) {
                fmt.Println("Del Addr")
            }
        }
    }
}

type NetlinkListener struct {
    fd int
    sa *syscall.SockaddrNetlink
}

func ListenNetlink() (*NetlinkListener, error) {
    groups := (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_LINK - 1)) |
        (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV4_IFADDR - 1)) |
        (1 << (syscall.RTNLGRP_IPV6_IFADDR - 1))

    s, err := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_NETLINK, syscall.SOCK_DGRAM,
        syscall.NETLINK_ROUTE)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("socket: %s", err)
    }

    saddr := &syscall.SockaddrNetlink{
        Family: syscall.AF_NETLINK,
        Pid:    uint32(0),
        Groups: uint32(groups),
    }

    err = syscall.Bind(s, saddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("bind: %s", err)
    }

    return &NetlinkListener{fd: s, sa: saddr}, nil
}

func (l *NetlinkListener) ReadMsgs() ([]syscall.NetlinkMessage, error) {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()

    pkt := make([]byte, 2048)

    n, err := syscall.Read(l.fd, pkt)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("read: %s", err)
    }

    msgs, err := syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage(pkt[:n])
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse: %s", err)
    }

    return msgs, nil
}

func IsNewAddr(msg *syscall.NetlinkMessage) bool {
    if msg.Header.Type == syscall.RTM_NEWADDR {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func IsDelAddr(msg *syscall.NetlinkMessage) bool {
    if msg.Header.Type == syscall.RTM_DELADDR {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

// rtm_scope is the distance to the destination:
//
// RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE   global route
// RT_SCOPE_SITE       interior route in the
// local autonomous system
// RT_SCOPE_LINK       route on this link
// RT_SCOPE_HOST       route on the local host
// RT_SCOPE_NOWHERE    destination doesn't exist
//
// The values between RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE and RT_SCOPE_SITE are
// available to the user.

func IsRelevant(msg *syscall.IfAddrmsg) bool {
    if msg.Scope == syscall.RT_SCOPE_UNIVERSE ||
        msg.Scope == syscall.RT_SCOPE_SITE {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```