# Detect network connection availability changes

Tags: go, winapi, networking

I am writing a Go application for Mac and Windows, which will perform some action whenever there is a network change( Client move from `Wi-fi 1` to `Wi-fi 2` or to 3G to LAN). I am aware of a solution for Application running on mac in swift language but I am looking for a platform-agnostic solution here.

So far I have tried checking for an event on an interface but I am not sure if that is sufficient.

I expect that on a network change (moving from Wifi-1 to Wifi-2 or 3G or LAN) my Go app should be able to know to take some action.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592607/get-ssid-other-network-information-in-golang

Comment: Thanks, should work for Wifi only on MAC and Linux but i need a solution for Wifi,LAN, Cellular on MAC,Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there would be such a solution.

Every project which tries to provide some platform-agnostic solution to an inherently OS-tied problem inevitably hides the platform-specific details behind a common API.
Look at https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify for a good example.

So, I'd take that route and would have put up a package which would have two platform-specific "backends" which would be compiled conditionally using build tags.

To get notified about network-related events under Windows,
you should probably start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Netlistmgr/nn-netlistmgr-inetworkevents).
Unfortunately, this stuff is COM-oriented, but you could use https://github.com/go-ole/go-ole to help with that.

You might also ask a non-Go-specific question tagged `winapi` to ask about what would be the best way to hook into the kernel to get notified about the availability of the networks.

Comment: Is there any similar way on OSx as well? i found netlink socket can help on linux but not on OSx.

Comment: I have zero experience with this platform. Quick googling turns up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/) which refers to [that](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability), in which the README discusses how to combine that with the stock `NSNotifications` to get notified. So I'd start there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no platform agnostic solution that exists, however platforms like OSx,Linux,Windiws has ways to get network events with their platform specific limitations.

**OSx**:   Raw socket SOCK_RAW of AF_ROUTE type can be used to detect any network events that occurs in user machine. there are various types of network event that can be detected.
[This thread talk about an example on BSD for network event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347807/how-to-monitor-ip-address-change-using-rtnetlink-socket-in-go-language)

**Windows** : Windows has its APIs given as part of iphlpapi library. APIs like NotifyAddrChange, NotifyRouteChange allows you to have almost all network events( apart from metric change etc.) [this git repo](https://gist.github.com/LiamHaworth/72f96c28fc90936904ba70ae5299218f) has a working example NotifyAddrChange, which gives back and event whenever a interface goes down or comes up.

**Linux** : In Linux netlink sockets allows a user space application to receive network events using netlink sockets.